# How to close overlay

Tags: jquery

actually how to close overlay that i already apeended by click function, i mean when i click mini cart, the mini cart will show and rest of the page are overlayed, and when i close click button it come back to normal, other words, has jquery own specific method to remove element that i append before, thanks

```
          var docHeight = $(document).height();
   var overlay = $("<div id='overlay'></div>");

   $('#mini-cart').click(function() {   
   $("body").append(overlay);   
   $("#overlay")
      .height(docHeight)
      .css({
         'opacity' : 0.4,
         'position': 'absolute',
         'top': 0,
         'left': 0,
         'background-color': 'black',
         'width': '100%',
         'z-index': 5000
      });     
    });

   $('#close').click(function() {   
    $("body").remove(overlay);     
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the appended element, try:

[jquery remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/)  Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well as everything inside it. In addition to the elements themselves, all bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.

or

[jquery detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach() keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the DOM at a later time.

Example: `$( ".hello" ).remove();` here `$( ".hello" )` is the selector.

Comment: You are using it incorrectly. It should be overlay.remove()

Comment: So i just use the $(this).modal('show'); and $(this).modal('hide'); by bootstrap, thanks by the way @k-k